# Помогите с require в Реакте

Tags: javascript

хочу вставлять в require значение из стейта для того что менять src в img. Но выходит ошибка Failed to compile.

```
    state = {
        aboutUsContent: [
            {img: '"../../images/"Rectangle 2 copy 2.jpg'},
            {img: '"../../images/"Rectangle 2 copy 3-2.jpg'},
            {img: '"../../images/"Rectangle 2 copy 3.jpg'}
        ]
    }
  const movingUp= ()=>{
            ++count
            let image = document.getElementById('imageSlide')
            if(count==6){
                count=0
            }
            image.scr={require({this.state.aboutUsContent[0].img})} // Не работает 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решается с помощью  таких ковычек `` пример

```
 let imgsrc = require(`../../images/logos/image${count}.jpg`)
```

Answer (score -2):

Я конечно не знаком с реакт, но вродебы правильно писать image.src

Comment: да ошибся, но это не меняет проблемы с require